# Infinite LaunchedEffect in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Jetpack Compose and my problem is that I'm trying to get data (JSON) from the server after navigation and I'm getting an infinite loop with `LaunchedEffect`.

My UI code  :

```
@Composable
fun ListView(
    viewModelItems: ItemsViewModel = viewModel(),
) {
    var stateData = remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    if(stateData.value == 0) {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            viewModelItems.getList()
            viewModelItems.state.collectLatest {
                stateData.value = it.state
            }
        }
    }


    when(stateData.value){
        ...
    }
```

I think this is a problem with `stateData` because it is not updated after recomposition.

My ViewModel code :

```
class ItemsViewModel : ViewModel(){

    private var listState = MutableStateFlow<ListState>(Loading(null, 0))

    var state =  listState.asStateFlow()

    fun getList(){
        val res = SkovService.getInstance().getList()

        res.enqueue(object : Callback<Items?>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Items?>, response: Response<Items?>) {
                listState.value = Success(response.body(), 1)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Items?>, t: Throwable) {
                listState.value = Error(null, -1)
                call.cancel()
            }

        })
    }
}
```

ListState is a `sealed class`  .

I've been trying to solve this problem for 1 week =D, if you know how to solve it, please help me.

Comment: Why have the `collect()` call? Why not use `viewModeltems.state.collectAsState()` outside of the `LaunchedEffect`? See https://blog.sentry.io/getting-started-with-jetpack-compose/ and https://www.composables.com/tutorials/state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @commonsware said, you can avoid using the `LaunchedEffect` and use the `collectAsState` with the `ListState` object itself. Then there will be no need for the -1, 0 and 1 within the `ListState` class and you can just use the type of the `ListState` within the `when` clause

```
@Composable
fun ListView(
    viewModelItems: ItemsViewModel = viewModel(),
) {
    val stateData by viewModelItems.state.collectAsState()

    when (stateData.value) {
       is Loading -> { // render loading components }
       is Error -> { // render error components }
       is Success -> { // use state value received from response.body() to render the list }
}
```

And you would need to call `viewModelItems.getList()` outside of this `@Composable`, or you can call it in the `init` block of the `ItemsViewModel`

Comment: thanks, now i call this function in the __init__ block but i get the same problem - infinite loop, code : 

init {
        if(state.value is Loading) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                getList()
            }
        }
    }